# FQL: Find all posts a user has contributed to

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm currently trying to find all the posts,comments, or likes I have made on all my friends walls. My solution right now is to find all my friends, and then query each ones stream, and then check each post in that stream for whether I was the author, or if I commented or liked it. The problem is it makes FQL queries for every single post on every single friends walls. It takes minutes just to do one friend, and hours to do my entire friend list.

Is there an easier/faster way to query all my contributions to a friends wall besides my current method?

Comment: you found an answer by any chance?

Comment: I just did what I described, waited hours/days for it to finish. I think you can download all your own data now from FB.